# Input field autocompleted, despite autocomplete="off"

Tags: html, forms, autocomplete

We're using a honeypot field to prevent bot subscriptions on an email subscription form:

```
<input type="text" name="email" size="25" value=">
<input type="text" name="hp123" tabindex="-1" autocomplete="off" value="" style="position: absolute; left:-5000px;">
```

If the hidden `hp123` field contains a value when the form is submitted, our back end returns a 'bot detected' error and the submission is ignored.

This works well for the majority of submissions, however we've had multiple complaints from human users who have somehow triggered the error message.

They've confirmed that they can't see the hidden field, so something is likely to be autocompleting on their behalf.

Are there any further steps I can take to prevent this? Autocomplete is set to off, the name is randomised, and the input is outside of view.

Comment: according to http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-autocomplete-onoff not all browser support autocomple=off

Answer (score 0):

Try setting autocomplete="new-password"